# How to properly ensure equal functionality of different implementations?

Tags: unit-testing, coding-style

I've got a project where I have several implementations which are stateless and should provide the same results for the same input (but use different internal APIs) and need therefore be tested to deliver equal results for equal inputs no matter which implementation is used.

Imagine something like

```
class TripleByMultiplication : ITripler {
    public double Triple(double value){ return value * 3; }
}
class TripleByAddition : ITripler {
    public double Triple(double value){ return value + value + value; }
}
```

Traditionally, ensuring that would be the subject of unit tests, where you would write for each class tests in a separate file that ensure compatibility for an implementation. I don't really like this idea, as it would mean a significant code duplication and I would need to keep track of changes in each test class.

While my intuition says use inheritance for this case, I'm aware that inheritance is regarded as something bad in test projects, it's currently the only way I'm aware of conducting these tests in a manageable manner.

I'd be highly interested how that can be done in a proper way.

Comment: I think the more worring thing is why do you have code that does the same thing in differnt ways i nthe first place? its not necessarily wrong but it feels very much a DRY violation

Comment: well, looking from a DRY perspective - yes. But I use this to abstract several computation options, like for OpenCL, AVX, SSE4.1 and one method which uses pointers to achieve a decent speedup.
In a perfect world, I could use AVX for all machines, but that would exclude all ARM and elder machines.

Answer (score 1):

> you would write for each class tests in a separate file that ensure compatibility for an implementation

Don't be dogmatic about this. If you have two implementations which under all circumstances *should* have the same functionality, then just write one set of and run the tests twice with the different implementations.

Comment: You can put `class TripleByMultiplicationTest { void Test() { new TripleTest(new TripleByMultiplication()).Test(); }` in a separate file to `TripleByAdditionTest`